# make target as a source in ODI 12c - flow mapping

Tags: oracle, oracle-data-integrator

in ODI 12c a mapping can load a data from a source to the target, but sometimes there is a need in the same mapping that the target could be another source for a new target, 
i.e. 
Source -> target (as if source) -> target and so on...
what is the best methodology to achieve that i read about reusable mapping and lookup component but what would be the most feasible and scientific way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use mapping but you should have multiple data models as your source and target.
Here is an example for two different sources and two different targets.as you can see in the shape below:

we have two sources include file technology (DM_FILE_AS_SOURCE data model) and oracle technology (DM_ORACLE_AS_SOURCE_TARGET data model) and two targets include oracle technology (DM_ORACLE_AS_SOURCE_TARGET data model) and another oracle technology (DM_ORACLE_AS_TARGET data model).
the mapping is very simple and type of "Control Append" that is working well.
hope this sample help you.